# Where is some methods implemented in the Kotlin source code?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

If I want to find out how any method is implemented in Java, I can always move to its declaration by pressing `Ctrl+B` on it in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and then jump to the implementation with `Ctrl+Alt+B`.

However, in some cases for Kotlin, my IDE only writes `No implementations found`. For example, I found no implementation of any methods in Kotlin's `ArrayList` and `LinkedHashMap`.

Where should I look for a method implementation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking `CTRL+B` you should be moved* to `TypeAliasesKt.class` to this line:

```kotlin
@kotlin.SinceKotlin public typealias LinkedHashMap<K, V> = java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>
```

with cursor on the left side, move it to right side and click `CTRL+B` again, then you should be moved to source. It's because `LinkedHashMap` is just an `typealias` of java `LinkedHashMap`.

*in this place there should be prompt window asking about decompiling sources, you should click `Yes`.